# What would cause a printing delay from only some apps?

Tags: windows-xp, printing

- WordPerfect 11 (sorry!) takes 30 seconds or so to start printing a document
- Adobe Reader 9 takes a long while as well
- Internet Explorer starts printing in just a few seconds, pretty much the expected behavior

**This started happening this week**, no new software installations recently. Printer is HP LaserJet 4000 TN on LPT1. Removing and re-adding the printer does not help. XP Pro SP3.

I found a [Microsoft KB about printing performance](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893225) and [an associated hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=893225&kbln=en-us). I have not tried applying this patch yet, but I will if other suggestions don't work.

Comment: Printer model may help

Comment: clean-up the spooler http://theonlinetutorials.com/how-to-clean-print-spooler-in-windows-vistaxp2003.html <-- This has caused some people far worse problems (backup first). A manual cleanup of any leftovers in the spooler might be better/safer. Then General cleanup speedup, Clear your temps, and then Full defrag the disk . most of these printer drivers access the spooler and write to disk the rendered image to sent to the printer, having a nice Sequential disk location could help a lot.  Could also be fun new unnessisary driver piles.

Answer (score 1):

Some applications take a while to start printing. Word processors take longer, as they quite often interrogate the printer driver for print metrics before they can start creating the document to print. As such, I'm not surprised WordPerfect takes a little longer to start printing. Adobe Reader X is out, you could try upgrading to that and seeing if that helps at all. IE doesn't care so much about print fidelity, so it can start printing quicker.

That hot fix is for XP SP2, and if you have SP3 installed you likely already have it, so the installing it probably won't help.